# gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received from ubuntu 16 curl(7.47.0)

Tags: server, curl, openssl, gnutls

am facing this issue when triggering curl to a target application hosted in ubuntu 20.

curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received,Below is the curl version in source.

curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3

Interstingly when i trigger curl from another machine where curl version is different,its working

Working curl version as below.

curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3

I can see that the difference that in working curl version there is openssl instead of gnutls as source package.

Any reason why gnutls is having handshake issue with ubuntu 20(same curl(7.47) is working against application in ubuntu 16)?

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: FYI:  The same user programs that work in a Ubuntu Core 16 product run in the Ubuntu Core 20 product; ie. that;'s a benefit of the *snap* only *year* products, in that the base OS upgrades; but user applications do not change (unlike with the far more common *year.month* products like 16.04 & 20.04).   Your package `curl | 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.19 | xenial-updates   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x` relates to an unsupported release; where *focal* is using `curl | 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7  | focal-updates    | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`

Comment: The working version you mention is `curl | 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.16 | bionic-updates   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` but that isn't packaged for 16.04 or 20.04; nor Ubuntu Core 16 or 20. Your question & versions don't align https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=curl&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all